# is it possible to design multileval multiselect menu using angular select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
<select ng-model="Category.CategoryId" ng-options="template.CategoryId as template.CategoryName for template in Adminsubcat">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Category</option>
                <option ng-repeat="j in template.Adminsubcat">{{j.CategoryName}}</option>
            </select>
```

my data in json

```
 "GetadminClassifiedCategoryListResult":
[
    {
        "AddedBy": 0,
        "AddedOn": null,
        "CategoryIcon": "icon-library_books",
        "CategoryId": 221,
        "CategoryName": "FBVGSDFBDFBDF",
        "ClassifiedSubCategory":
        [
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 238,
                "CategoryName": "zcvb",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 237,
                "CategoryName": "poiyu",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 236,
                "CategoryName": "oi",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 235,
                "CategoryName": "uy",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 234,
                "CategoryName": "tr",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 233,
                "CategoryName": "hjjjhjghjhgjghjhgjgjghhgjghj",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 232,
                "CategoryName": "fghgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgf",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 231,
                "CategoryName": "trfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgf",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 230,
                "CategoryName": "gfhfhgfhgfhgfh",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 229,
                "CategoryName": "fdgdfgdgdfgdfgdfgdf",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 228,
                "CategoryName": "sdfgsdgdf",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 227,
                "CategoryName": "dsgsdfgsdgsdg",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 223,
                "CategoryName": "fhhhhhhhhhhgfhgf",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            },
            {
                "AddedBy": 0,
                "AddedOn": null,
                "CategoryIcon": "",
                "CategoryId": 222,
                "CategoryName": "dfhfdhdfhdfhdf",
                "DeletedBy": 0,
                "DeletedOn": null,
                "IsActive": false,
                "ModifiedBy": 0,
                "ModifiedOn": null,
                "ParentCategoryId": 221
            }
        ],
        "DeletedBy": 0,
        "DeletedOn": null,
        "IsActive": false,
        "ModifiedBy": 0,
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "ParentCategoryId": 0
    },
```

in json data ClassifiedSubCategory has list of sub category.i want to display multilevel dropdown with multiselct  options.is possible using angular select or I have to use ul li. suggest any js avavilable. it is possible using ng-repeat start.
it has treestructure

category

- subcategory
- subcategory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two select boxes for selecting category and sub-category. I have used a simpler json to explain the concept.

```
angular.module('my-app', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [{
      "CategoryId": 1,
      "CategoryName": "Category A",
      "subCategories": [{
          "CategoryId": 101,
          "CategoryName": "Sub-Category A1"
        }, {
          "CategoryId": 102,
          "CategoryName": "Sub-Category A2"
        }

      ]
    }, {
      "CategoryId": 2,
      "CategoryName": "Category B",
      "subCategories": [{
          "CategoryId": 201,
          "CategoryName": "Sub-Category B1"
        }, {
          "CategoryId": 202,
          "CategoryName": "Sub-Category B2"
        }

      ]
    }]

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="my-app">
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  Category:
  <select ng-model="Category" ng-options="template as template.CategoryName for template in categories">
  </select>
  Sub Category:
  <select ng-model="SubCategory" ng-options="template as template.CategoryName for template in Category.subCategories">
  </select>
  <p>
    Selected Category: {{Category.CategoryId}}
    <br /> Selected Sub Category: {{SubCategory.CategoryId}}
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: can it possible with one select.

Comment: @VaibhavSave No. You need two selects. The only way to have it in one select is to use optgroups, and that doesn't sound like what you want. Unless you find some third-party-plugin that is.

Answer (score 0):

Tks guys for all your help.i have tried something thav give me all category and subcategory.i think I can apply css to look like multilevel menu.

```
<select ng-model="Category.CategoryId">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Category</option>
                <option ng-repeat-start="m in Adminsubcat" >{{m.CategoryName}}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="j in m.ClassifiedSubCategory" ng-repeat-end>{{j.CategoryName}}</option>
               @* <option ng-repeat-end></option>*@
            </select>
```